# Suppressing rsyslog tls error messages

Tags: rsyslog

When configuring rsyslog with tls and using `PermittedPeer` or `streamdriver.authmode` name, if an unauthorized peer connects, rsyslog logs error messages like below.

```
Jan 22 08:56:38 test rsyslogd-2089: netstream session 0x7f177401b740 from 10.0.0.7 will be closed due to error  [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2089 ]
Jan 22 08:56:38 test rsyslogd-2088: error: peer name not authorized -  not permitted to talk to it. Names: DNSname: *.test.com; DNSname: test.com; CN: *.test.com;  [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2088 ]
```

If the client is persistent, rsyslog logs thousands of these messages.

Is there a way to tell the netstream driver to not log too many of these? I wouldn't mind seeing them to figure out which client is misconfigured or possible abuse, but there is just too many of these.

I am currently using the below entries, which completely discard these messages.

```
:msg, contains, "peer name not authorized" ~
:msg, regex, ".*netstream session .* from .* will be closed due to error" ~
```

This by the way generates the below warning message, even though [recent documentation](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/actions.html#discard) says this is the correct way to discard messages.

```
Jan 22 09:34:22 test: warning: ~ action is deprecated, consider using the 'stop' statement instead [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2307 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to implement [RepeatedMsgReduction](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsconf1_repeatedmsgreduction.html).

In your global configuration directives (probably `rsyslog.conf`):

```
$RepeatedMsgReduction on
```

From the Docs:

> This directive specifies whether or not repeated messages should be reduced (this is the "Last line repeated n times" feature). If set to on, repeated messages are reduced. If set to off, every message is logged.

Comment: That is a global option and doesn't have a way to specify which messages should be reduced. I don't want other messages that might be repeating to be reduced. Also, not sure how repeated is calculated but, on a busy server, there will be a lot of other messages in between these, making them not repetitive.